# Where does Itunes keep bought apps?

Tags: macos, ipod-touch

I bought the Software Update 3.0 for my two iPod touches.

I would like to put the same Software Update onto my second iPod touch so I do not need to pay twice for the same update.

**Where does iTunes keep the iPod touch and iPhone Software Updates in OS X Leopard?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you probably do need to pay for it twice. When you 'bought' it, you (presumably) payed for a **single** licence for a **single** device.

Regardless, on OS X Leopard, it should be in:

```
Library/iTunes
```

Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Your Windows username>\Application Data\
    Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates
```

And in Vista/7:

```
 C:\Users\<Your Windows username>\AppData\Local\Apple Computer\iTunes\
    iPhone Software Updates
```

On the other hand, to see where the iPod touch and iPhone applications are, just right click one and select 'Show in Explorer/Finder'

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your edits which you made you for my question!

Comment: But if you find the .ipa, can you install it on another device magically? (I haven't tried.)

Comment: Jt: I think it will work, but I am not 100% sure

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you paid for or what the license restrictions are.  As others have mentioned, it may be that you are entitled to apply the update to only a single device.  It's also possible that there is DRM enforcement of this restriction.

On Mac OS X, iPod Touch OS updates are stored in:

```
~/Library/iTunes/iPod Software Updates
```

and iPhone OS updates are stored in:

```
~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Updates
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is stored in a temporary folder somewhere. I know it sucks, but it might be best just to pay the extra $10 to get it upgraded properly.